# Specific y-axis limitation in nether fortresses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I spawned near the ceiling in the nether.  However, I'm trying to make the best of things and find a nether fortress anyway.  I've found my way to lower levels and have been digging steadily west a while.

Is there a specific y-axis limitation in which nether fortresses spawn or should I just keep digging?

Comment: I don't think they spawn underground.  But I could be wrong.  I was under the impression they were always accessible from the surface, with no digging required.

Comment: Related Question:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75073/any-useful-strategies-for-finding-a-nether-fortress

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation in where Nether Fortresses spawn.

Normally they are spawned at lava level.