# What do I if i got a bad nether fortress and cant find nether wart

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing minecraft and got lucky that my portal was near the fortress but I got the one lava chamber with no indoor loot areas and i looked north and south for the other nether fortress but I could find any. I need help finding nether warts because I'm trying to start making potions for zombie villagers I looked for the piglin chamber and still havent found any nether warts. I'm getting so desperate to find this stuff that I copied my world went on creative and still have fould a single nether wart. Any thing I can do to get nether other than those two?

Comment: There are more then one fortresses, you will just have to find them.

Answer (score 1):

[Find](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371756/minecraft-1-16-nether-fortress-location-generation) another Nether fortress, nothing to it. Even without the Nether wart chamber not all is lost - some chests in Nether Fortress contain nether wart too. Also, if you find a bastion, some of them have nether wart in the 'treasure chamber'.

But in essence, keep exploring. Barter with piglins to get some potions of fire resistance, ender pearls, soul speed boots, and have patience - you only need a little of nether wart to start a farm of your own, so even if you find it very far, that's not a trip you have to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Some might consider it cheating, but you could make a copy of your level (or make a new level with the same seed) allowing cheats within the copy. Go into the nether in creative mode and use the /locate command to find a different nether fortress. Note the coordinates. Then load your non-cheat world and head for those coordinates.