# Finding a nether fortress

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I cannot find a nether fortress in my bedrock world. I have traveled about 700 blocks on the z axis (while moving about 20 blocks to the side every 100 blocks) and I still haven’t found one. I don’t want to make a creative copy and just fly around until I find one and save the coordinates. What should I do? Edit: I consider things like Chunkbase cheating, I was mainly talking about a strategy instead of mindlessly wandering over the lava ocean.

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75073/any-useful-strategies-for-finding-a-nether-fortress) but technically not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> While Nether Fortresses can be found scattered across the Nether in Minecraft, their spawning isn't entirely random. Nether Fortresses are more likely to spawn on the positive side of the X-axis, therefore moving north or south while keeping the X-axis positive is the best way to search for them. Following this line, keeping lighting and render distance high, and maneuvering for an unobstructed view should give players the best chance of finding a Nether Fortress in Minecraft.

[GameRant](https://gamerant.com/find-nether-fortress-minecraft/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/locate` command.

To use commands, first enable cheats. Then use:

- `/locate structure fortress` (Minecraft 1.19+)

**OR**

- `/locate fortress` (Minecraft 1.11 to 1.18)

Natural Search: Exploring the Nether dimension and finding the Fortress in common spots

Tips include but are not limited to:

- Blazes and Wither skeletons only spawn in the Nether fortresses. If you find them, you can also find the nearest Nether fortress.
- Minecraft divides the Nether into different regions. Some of them generate bastions, while others generate fortresses. So, it’s best to avoid looking in the regions with a bastion in them.

Answer (score 0):

My only other suggestion would be to methodically search quadrants rather than just search randomly, but this can be tedious and I understand any hesitation to use this method.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely OP is very unlucky.

Either that, or structure spawning is disabled. As far as I know there's no really good way to track down nether fortresses reliably fast, it's mostly just luck.